# Kendo cascasding DropDownlists and available dropdown items

Tags: html, mvvm, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI to create a cascading dropdownlists.
The problem is the second and third dropdowns in the cascade only have 1 of the 3 items that should be in them.

The HTML

```
<div id="goodies">
        <input id="uno"  data-bind="source: unoTypes, value: uno" />
        <input id="dos"  data-bind="source: dosTypes, value: dos" />
        <input id="tres"  data-bind="source: tresTypes, value: tres" />
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
data = window.kendo.observable({
    uno: null,
    dos: null,
    tres: null,
    baseRomType: null,
    unoTypes: [
                { name: "Bing", id: 1 },
                { name: "Bang", id: 2 },
                { name: "Bong", id: 3 }
    ],
    dosTypes: [
              { name: "Ding", id: 1 },
              { name: "Dang", id: 2 },
              { name: "Dong", id: 3 }
    ],
    tresTypes: [
              { name: "Ring", id: 1 },
              { name: "Rang", id: 2 },
              { name: "Rong", id: 3 }
    ],


});

window.kendo.bind($("#goodies"), data);

$('#uno').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: 'Please Select for Uno'
});

$('#dos').kendoDropDownList({

    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: 'Please Select for Dos',
    cascadeFrom: "uno"
});

$('#tres').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: 'Please Select for Tres',
    cascadeFrom: "dos"
});
```

See the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRLvr/2/)

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug? I'm on KendoUI 2013.Q1 (2013.1.319)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across it and figured I would provide an answer in case others are having similar issue.

From what I can tell, you don't actually need cascading dropdowns, but instead you just want to enable the next dropdown after the previous one has been selected (as opposed to cascading which would filter the items in the next dropdown based on the option selected in the previous dropdown)?

First, update your HTML to add *enabled* bindings.

```
<div id="goodies">
    <input id="uno"  data-bind="source: unoTypes, value: uno" />
    <input id="dos"  data-bind="source: dosTypes, enabled: uno, value: dos" />
    <input id="tres"  data-bind="source: tresTypes, enabled: dos, value: tres" />
</div>
```

Then, update your javascript to remove the *cascadeFrom* settings:

```
$('#dos').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: 'Please Select for Dos',
    //cascadeFrom: "uno"
});

$('#tres').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    optionLabel: 'Please Select for Tres',
    //cascadeFrom: "dos"
});
```

You can see upated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FRLvr/9/)